# Can't use "/usr/bin/env" in C execve() call on macOS

Tags: c, macos, macos-catalina, execve

I couldn't really find any relevant results after looking for a while, so I'm asking this myself. I have the following C code, which tries to execute `nasm` through `execve()` via `/usr/bin/env` so I don't have to hardcode the path to the executable.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    char *cmds[10] = {"/usr/bin/env", "nasm", "--version", NULL};
    execve(cmds[0], cmds, NULL);
}
```

On linux (Ubuntu 18/20), it works fine:

```sh
linux $ gcc test.c && ./a.out
NASM version 2.13.02
linux $
```

However, on macOS (Catalina, at least), I get the following:

```sh
macos $ gcc test.c && ./a.out                                                                                                                            
env: nasm: No such file or directory
macos $
```

I'm not exactly sure what the difference is. I do have NASM installed, I can run `nasm --version` on my terminal just fine. It also works fine if I hardcode the path `/usr/local/bin/nasm` to the `execve()` call. If I try to run the following manually on my terminal, it also seems to work:

```sh
macos $ /usr/bin/env nasm --version
NASM version 2.15.05 compiled on Aug 29 2020
macos $
```

The reason I want to use `/usr/bin/env` is that the default install location for `nasm` is different for different OSs, and I don't want to just hardcode the paths.

Comment: Probably your programs environment doesn't have the full `PATH` that your shell have (i.e. the `PATH` in your program doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`). Try printing the result of `getenv("PATH")` from inside your program to see what it might be.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the idea, but it seems that `getenv("PATH")` does have the correct path, which includes `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `execve`.

The `e` suffix means you pass an environment to the `exec` system call, but the environment you pass is `NULL`. Which means *no environment at all*.

Use `execv` instead to use the same environment as the calling program.

Comment: That's... incredibly silly of me. I guess I just got thrown off by it working on Linux. In any case, my real problem was with trying to do this directly through syscalls in assembly, so I guess my actual solution here would be to pass `envp` to `execve()`